# difference in code between using nn.RNN or not

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

hi im new to rnn's and I found [RNN NLP FROM SCRATCH](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) from pytorch official tutorials, and I think it's named "from scartch" because it didn't use the `nn.RNN` built in `nn` in pytorch some line like this `self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)` in the `def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):` segment. so how to the code would have been evolved if the `nn.RNN` was been used?

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    # implement RNN from scratch rather than using nn.RNN
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
        
    def forward(self, input_tensor, hidden_tensor):
        combined = torch.cat((input_tensor, hidden_tensor), 1)
        
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden
    
    def init_hidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
def train(line_tensor, category_tensor):
    hidden = rnn.init_hidden()
    
    for i in range(line_tensor.size()[0]):
        output, hidden = rnn(line_tensor[i], hidden)
        
    loss = criterion(output, category_tensor)
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    return output, loss.item()
```

another equivalent to this question is how to rewrite the code with using `self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)` or if it's not possible how internal `nn.RNN` structure look like?

Answer (score 1):

This model is referring the implementation of RNN before autograde module introduce, it is a pure implementation of `RNN`. In this example hidden state and gradient entirely handled by graph.

```
def init_hidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
```

the line above initializes the hidden state(which is zeros at first). and after first step we get the `output` and next `hidden state` which later feed in the next step.

All this process handle by `graph`.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and added that I think because the `self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)` is not used it's been called  "from scratch" so why you think it's named from scratch. and where is "autograde module introduce"

Comment: ok if this one is also is implemtation of rnn, I want one that uses self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True) in it please.

Comment: can you answer it?